# Sort Eloquent Models by related table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table in which I save movies, and then I have another table, where I save the price for the movie dependent on the age. Each age has a different price. What I now want to do, is to get all movies for a specific age, and sort it by price.

My `movies` table looks like this

`id - name`

My `prices` table looks like this

`id - movie_id - age - price`

To get the data I'm using the following code

```
/** @var Builder $movies */
// We now get only the movies where the user's age is listed in the price table
$movies = Movie::whereHas('prices', function ($query) use ($age) {
    /** @var Builder $query */
    $query->where('age', $age);
});
```

That way I'm getting only movies which are for a specific age. However, now I want to sort them by price. How would I do that? I tried to use `with` instead of `whereHas` to get the relation and then order it by the pivot table, but the problem is, that when I use `with` I'm getting 83 movies, however, when using `whereHas` I'm getting 76 results. 76 is the correct number, since when I use SQL to get all movies with prices for 23 years old I'm getting 76

`SELECT COUNT(id) FROM prices WHERE age = 23; // 76`

When googling I found many people who where using `join` methods instead of the Eloquent methods. Is this really the only possibility to go?

Comment: yes, you have to join, because ->with() will get you additional data, and not very usefull for one-to-one relationships

Comment: I haven't try this. can you try this `$query->where('age', $age)->orderBy('price');` ?

Comment: I guess it can't be done on the database side without joining. It could be done in the PHP side, however. I'd take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-collections#available-methods

Comment: I am author of a package that deals with this https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable just open up code and see for your self how I solved it (oneToOneRelation).